# Character (and related story) behind actress Peggy Connelly in Houseboat (1958)

Tags: alternate-version, houseboat

Actress Peggy Connelly apparently had a role in Houseboat, the 1958 U.s. movie starring Cary Grant and Sophia Loren. Her scenes were cut. I cannot find what her role was, and what part of the story her scenes would have added.

Answer (score 1):

Her character name was Elizabeth Wilson([Source: IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0175101/)).

That said, I haven't found any information about the deleted scenes so far.

Comment: Yeah, that's readily available from IMDB. That's where I saw that her scenes had been cut. I'm looking for the role of her character, as in, was she the former maid or another child, or what?